# R: how to fix axis extension in base plot

Tags: r, plot

I have a Rscript script that plots traces as lines.  The problem I have is that the offset (the space between y-axis and the start of the plotted lines) changes proportional to the number of data points, the more data points the greater the offset, as shown in the example plots on the page https://mitomap.org/trace.html.

How can I get the offset fixed so it's not affected by the number of data points?

Below are the relevant codes in the script.  I also tried ggplot() and got the same problem.

```
plot(data$x, data$trace1, type="l", col="black", ylim=c(0,50))
lines(data$x, data$trace2 type="l", col="red")
lines(data$x, data$trace3, type="l", col="green")
lines(data$x, data$trace4, type="l", col="#888888")
```

While on it, any one can suggest four colors that can better distinguish from each other. In the plots on the above pages, the black, green and red colors distinguish from each other very well, but I can't find a satisfying fourth color that can distinguish from all other tree colors very well. For example, brown, magenta are hard to tell from red, blue from black, cyan from green, etc. Yellow and pink are very faint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can force `plot` to not extend the axis range by 4% of the data range (default) by setting the `xaxs` style parameter. Moreover, you can specify a shared axis range with `xlim` (see `?par`):

```
plot(..., xaxs = 'i')
```

In ggplot, you would set the `expand` argument of the scale, e. g.:

```
## ggplot code +
scale_x_continous(..., expand = c(0, 0))
## with the expansion helper:
scale_x_continous(..., expand = expansion(mult = 0, add = 0))
```

For palettes, see [colorbrewer](https://colorbrewer2.org/).

Comment: Thanks.  I tried xaxs='i' and it eliminated the space between y-axis and the trace plot, but the plots are expanded proportional to the number of data points along x-axis. So the three plots all start at the y-axis, but the data points at the same positions are not aligned vertically.  But any way this is a different issue.

Comment: Does setting the axis limits explictly (`plot(..., xlim = c(0, 1500))`) help?

Comment: It will probably fix the expansion issue, but that's not practical because the number of data points are dynamic (change from experiment to experiment ranging from hundreds to thousands).  But this issue is less important.  Thanks again for your help.